# Invert ListView Order and Display Without Scrolling

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to invert a ListView so that the most recent items appear first. I have seen results that state to modify the getItem() method, however that requires me scrolling down and scrolling back up to see the new item. Is there a way to have the item appear at the top of the list without requiring the need to scroll?

```
 public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Comments> {

    Firebase BaseRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    Firebase PollsRef = mBaseRef.child(POLLS_LABEL);
    Firebase UpdateRef = mPollsRef.child(mCurrentDateString).child(String.valueOf(mPollIndex + 1));
    Firebase CommentsRef = mUpdateRef.child(COMMENTS_LABEL);
    int pollCommentCount;


    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Comments> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        CommentsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                pollCommentCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Log.v("POLL_COMMENT_COUNT", "The poll comment count is " + pollCommentCount);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
        return pollCommentCount;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.individual_comment, null);
        }

        Comments p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView userID = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_ID);
            TextView userComment = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_comment);

            if (userID != null) {
                userID.setText(p.getUserID());
            }

            if (userComment != null) {
                userComment.setText(p.getUserComment());
            }
        }


        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you sort the `Comments` list before you send it to the adapter? Possibly with `Collections`?

Comment: Can you post sample code?

Comment: Sort your backing list with Collections.sort and a comparator using your model's recency as the field on which to compare.  Then call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter to inform the ListView that it needs to refresh itself.

Comment: I added an example of how to sort the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the `Comment` list before creating your adapter. This way they are already in the order you want them to be in. I don't know what variable the `Comment` object contains that lets you know when it was modified, but assuming it is a date, you can sort the list like this:

```
Collections.sort(commentsList, new Comparator<Comment>() {
    public int compare(Comment c1, Comment c2) {
        return c1.getDate().compareTo(c2.getDate());
    }
});
```

You can also simply reverse the list with `Collections.reverse(commentList)`

Comment: I actually used Collections.reverse(mCommentArrayList) and it worked! A variant if you want to change your answer.

Comment: Actually, the problem I am having now is that I am continuously reversing the list and thus it is not displaying the most recent comments

Comment: Yeah. So sorting is probably the better option. That way no matter how many times it is sorted it will always be the correct order

Answer (score 0):

Calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` should update the list.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the .add() method actually inserts the item at a specific index. If I am always adding new items to index(0), then the items will naturally appear in reverse order.

I thought Google would have been more intuitive with the Android code and allowed for an insert() method, but the add() method at index(o) serves the purpose:

```
mUpdateRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            setImage(dataSnapshot);
            setQuestion(dataSnapshot);
            createInitialCommentIDArray(dataSnapshot);
            mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll = (int) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).getChildrenCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < mNumberOfCommentsAtPoll; i++) {
                String commentID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("COMMENT").getValue();
                Log.v("COMMENT_ID", "The comment ID is " + commentID);
                String userID = (String) dataSnapshot.child(COMMENTS_LABEL).child(mCommentIDArrayList.get(i)).child("USER_ID").getValue();
                Log.v("USER_ID", "The user ID is " + userID);
                mCommentArrayList.add(0 , new Comments(mUserAvatar, userID, commentID));
                mCommentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
```